# GTK - How to know that the dropdown list of the GtkComboBoxText gets shown

Tags: drop-down-menu, gtk

A GtkComboBoxText consists of a text entry, a dropdown list and a button to show the dropdown list.

I want to populate the contents of the drop down box of a GtkComboBoxText when the user clicks on the dropdown button. This is because the drop down box needs to be repopulated with the data.

I found that pressing alt-down in the text entry generates the "popup" signal and opens the drop down box, but I can't find the right signal which one which matches the even when the dropdown button is pressed.

What would be the right signal I need to connect to?
Or is there another way to repopulate the contents of the dropdown list when it gets displayed?

Thanks in advance, Edwin

Answer (score 0):

The `popup` signal is a *keybinding* signal - instead of being emitted when the menu is opened, it is emitted when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd> and tells the combo box to open its menu. There is no signal emitted when the menu is opened.

Instead, you could try connecting to `key-press-event` and `button-press-event`. This will populate the menu more often than you really need to, but will ensure that it is up-to-date whenever the menu is shown. Don't forget to return `FALSE` from these signals so that the events are passed through to the signal handlers that normally handle them.

Alternatively, try repopulating the menu whenever the data it is generated from change, instead of every time it is shown. This makes more sense to me.